# What is the cost of CALEA in the US? (Lawful intercept)

Tags: legal, surveillance

The [Computer Assistance for Law Enforcement Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Assistance_for_Law_Enforcement_Act) (CALEA) is a law in the US that provides for lawful intercept of communications by law enforcement (namely, the FBI).

Specifically, as I understand it:

- The law requires telecommunications carriers to install compliant network equipment to technically provide this access.
- The government does not reimburse the telecoms for the cost of this equipment, which means that the cost is eventually passed onto the consumer.

My question:

- **Is there a estimate of the cumulative cost of providing CALEA compliance, since the passage of the law in ~1995?**

Comment: I'm not sure that this is on topic here. It would require that each telco disclose the costs for that time period.

Comment: I'm not sure how this doesn't qualify as in-scope, on the topics of "risk management" and "policies"; not to mention  that other questions have been asked re: security laws/policies. If your objection is that the answer is: "It's unknowable", feel free to post that as an answer! Though some further thoughtful analysis on the topic could be valuable.

Comment: Your question is about how much money all organizations have paid to comply. Cost considerations are of topic.

Comment: Sorry, but would you mind pointing me in the direction of the guideline that places the economics of security policies as off-topic? It doesn't appear to be mentioned at all on the page you linked in your close vote.

Comment: You aren't asking for the theoretical cost of implementing policies (which could be on topic), but you are asking for the realized, industry-wide, historical costs.

Comment: "Is there an estimate of the cumulative cost" - this is sufficiently vague to allow your interpretation (technically, it's a yes/no question!); or you could have edited it as such. I realize this is all moot, since in your dictatorial mod power you've shut down this line of inquiry, but you might want to think again about such a policy, if you want this site to thrive.

Comment: Note - I see that you're a new moderator. You might want to ease off, and let the community decide which questions it is inclined to answer, and grow organically, rather than force it in the Schroeder Direction.